# Serverless-offline - API REST node typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, rest, serverless

I created a project serverless and I am having a trouble:

```
sls create --template aws-nodejs-typescript
npm install serverless-offline --save-dev
```

then, inside the file serverless.ts I add in:

```
plugins: ['serverless-webpack', 'serverless-offline'],
```

So I run the project with the command:

```
serverless offline --stage dev
```

As response I have:

```
**POST | http://localhost:3000/dev/hello                              
POST | http://localhost:3000/2015-03-31/functions/hello/invocations**
```

The request with POST http://localhost:3000/dev/hello using body {“name”: “Andre”} don´t answer, I don´t know why the project don´t response to the request, it only show “sending request” in postman and keeps showing this. But if I use the address GET http://localhost:3000 I have a response saying that existing routes are:

```
{
    "currentRoute": "get - /",
    "error": "Serverless-offline: route not found.",
    "existingRoutes": [
        "post - /dev/hello"
    ],
    "statusCode": 404
}
```

Please, could you make this process? I Think there is a bug in the template that was created

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problema was the version of nodejs.

I was usgin node 16.

Now I am using node LTS 14.

Problem solved.